# Assigning Values to a TextView from a different class

Tags: android, class, android-layout, android-context, settext

TestaActivity.java

```
public class TestaActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tvText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tvText.setText("Sample");
    }
}
```

Print.java

```
public class Print {
    public Print(Context tempContext) {
        //I want to assign the value to the tvText from here
    }
}
```

In the above example, as you can see I have set the text in tvText to "Sample". In the same way, I need to assign the textView1 ID with some value inside Print class, once it is created.

Please help me to figure out the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as:

```
public class Print {
 protected TestaActivity  context;
    public Print(Context tempContext) {

        context = tempContext;
    }
     public void changetextViewtext(final String msg){
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                //assign the value to the tvText from here
                    context.tvText.setText("Hello Test");    
                }
            });
        }
}
```

and call `changetextViewtext` from Activity for Changeing TextView Text from `Print` Class

```
public class TestaActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tvText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tvText.setText("Sample");
        Print  myPrint  = new Print(this);
            myPrint.changetextViewtext("Hello World !!!");
    }
}
```

as your need!!!!:)

Answer (score 2):

If your class Print is instantiated when TestaActivity is on the screen, then you can get tvText reference, passing to Print in some way a TestaActivity reference.
Maybe you could pass it via constructor:

From TestaActivity you do:

```
Print print = new Print(this);
```

where this represents the instance of TestaActivity.
And then in your Print code you can do:

```
TextView tvText = (TextView)((TestaActivity)context.findViewById(R.id.textView1));
tvText.setText("Sample");
```

Another solution is provide an interface from TestaActivity, transparent for the outside, which manage your changes on the textview (or whatever).
Something like that:

```
 private TextView tvText;

 public void setTvText(String str){
      tvText.setText( str );
 }
```

And then in your Print class:

```
 ((TestaActivity)context).setTvText( "Sample" );
```

Answer (score 1):

@imran - the solution is correct except that you would want to pass the TextView as an argument in the constructor or the method.

Harcoding TextView in a method is bad because you cannot be reuse it.